# type ‘Null’ can’t be assigned to CustomClass type

Tags: flutter, dart

I had been working after a long time with flutter and this new null safety is just breaking my code.

I had created a data model class to store values as an object as follows:

```
class MyClass{
  int x;
  String y;
  MyClass({this.x, this.y});
  .. .. ..rest of the code
}
```

Now in a provider I am having a list of MyClass objects to store data from the db.
Over here I am using the firstWhere() to search for the required object by id.

```
MyClass getObj(int id){
   return list.firstWhere((obj) => obj.id == id, orElse: ()=>null);
}
```

But this keeps giving the error:

> type ‘Null’ cant be assigned as it isn’t a subtype of MyClass

I tried firstWhereOrNull and also other solutions but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting is because the return type of the `orElse` function must be non-nullable (in [the docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html), the signature is `E` and not `E?`).

If returning `null` from `getObj` is expected and you're prepared to handle that case elsewhere in code that calls `getObj`, then change the return type of the method to `MyClass?` (instead of `MyClass`) and use `firstWhereOrNull`, as you mentioned:

```dart
MyClass? getObj(int id){
  return list.firstWhereOrNull((obj) => obj.x == id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return null in non-nullable function. Try make MyClass nullable by adding? After MyClass like that

> `MyClass? getObj(int id){ return list.firstWhere((obj) => obj.id == id, orElse: ()=>null); }`